# algorithm for the validating the net-walk puzzle game

Tags: algorithm, actionscript-3, backtracking

What is a simplest algorithm for validating if all the connections have been made successfully and all the connections are closed?

I have laid the game tiles and the game is ready to play all i need is an algorithm to verify and make the changes to the connections when the user clicks on each tile every time.

for your reference a **[game](http://www.logicgamesonline.com/netwalk/)** like this one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One simple way would be to do a classic "Depth-First Search" (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search), where tiles are vertices.
Create a boolean variable which is initially "True".
Color in blue the tiles you manage to reach with a Depth First Search from the source, and refresh every time the user rotates a tile. While doing this, check if there are any leaks and give the variable the value "False" if it happens.
The puzzle is solved if all the vertices are visited and the variable is "True".